# Why there is not a PRNG or CSPRNG tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just came across this question: [Is getting 1-2 outputs from a CSPRNG to seed another CSPRNG less entropy than getting say 5000 outputs from a CSPRNG and using that to seed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/216058/is-getting-1-2-outputs-from-a-csprng-to-seed-another-csprng-less-entropy-than-ge)

I noticed that we do not have a tag for a CSPRNG or PRNG. Should'nt there be proper tags for both of these?

I created a pseudo-random-number-generator tag now, which also covers CSPRNG in the body.

**May I ask one of the higher-rep people to either approve, change or delete this new tag?**

Comment: There already is a `random` tag that covers both. I am not sure if more specific tags would be helpful or not here. Good question.

Comment: @Anders 'random' seems to be overly broad for questions specific to number generation IMHO, it could mean anything random, not just number generators.

Comment: Yeah, that is a valid point. I'm not sure people will use the tags in a good way, but maybe I am just being pessimistic. Anyways, there already is a `prng` tag that is a synonym of `random`. So whatever way we go, we have some cleanup to do.

Answer (score 5):

I would question if there is really a need for such tags. Ask yourself, why are there tags?

They should primarily help people find questions they can answer. For instance, [passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwords) is a really good tag, as it clearly encapsulates what questions will be about. Yes, there is some overlap with [password-management](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-management) or [password-cracking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-cracking), but if you feel reasonably confident in answering questions like "How do I pick a good password?" or "How should I store my passwords?", then the tag is right for you.

Likewise, [random](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) has the following usage guidance:

> The generation of random or pseudorandom data, and the use of randomness in security protocols

This seems like a pretty good usage guidance to me. It's about randomness, and how to use it. Tags like [prng](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prng) and [csprng](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csprng) would be quite redundant and not really help anybody.

Think to yourself, would it really make sense to make an [xss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xss) tag and additionally split it into [reflected-xss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflected-xss), [stored-xss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stored-xss) and [dom-xss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dom-xss)? No, it would just be overly complicated and make it *more* difficult to find interesting questions.

Comment: Not to mention, questions which go into that level of detail about cryptography belong on [crypto.se].